# Another time source for QML animations?

Tags: qt, animation, qml

I am thinking about building a gstreamer plugin that renders animated QML graphics for later overlaying onto playing video. So far the idea to use QML looks very promising to me, except one problem. I need to be able to seek within the video, and the animations must also rewind and jump to the required point in time. Now that I read QML docs, I see that all the animations are typically time bound.

So my question is: is it possible to bind QML animations to some "time source", other than the real world time, which may not be monotonous (in fact, it can be manipulated by the application). Or, more generically, can I bind QML animation to a numeric value X, so that when it changes, my animation progresses, and there is a strict relation between X and animation state. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: QML internal design is usually not very flexible, seems like the animation components are not an exception. Depending on what you want to do exactly there might be different ways to get around the problem. You can easily implement your custom animation, and it is not necessary that it follows the built in in is design. Some state tweakery might be all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is suitable only for `NumberAnimation` object. Probably similar approach can be used to replace other `Animation` objects as well.*

As already stated by [ddriver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/991484/ddriver) there is no other way than work around.

Here is my solution to the problem. It may seem complicated but I can assure it is easy to use. At the end of this answer I put a link to the source code of example project using this code. You can try it.

Add these files to your project:

- easingvalueforprogress.h

```
#ifndef EASINGVALUEFORPROGRESS_H
#define EASINGVALUEFORPROGRESS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QEasingCurve>

class EasingValueForProgress : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit EasingValueForProgress(QObject *parent = 0);

    Q_INVOKABLE double getValue(int easingEnum, double progress){
        QEasingCurve easing((QEasingCurve::Type)easingEnum);
        return easing.valueForProgress(progress);
    }

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // EASINGVALUEFORPROGRESS_H
```

- easingvalueforprogress.cpp

```
#include "easingvalueforprogress.h"

EasingValueForProgress::EasingValueForProgress(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}
```

- XValueAnimation.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id: xValueAnimator

    property Item target
    property string targetProperty
    property double from
    property double to
    property int easing: Easing.Linear
    property double xValue

    onXValueChanged: {
        if (target.hasOwnProperty(targetProperty)) {
            target[targetProperty] = calculateCurrentValue(
                        from, to, easing, xValue);
        }
        else
            console.error("XValueAnimator: target:", target,
                          "does not have property", targetProperty)
    }

    function calculateCurrentValue(
        defaultFrom, defaultTo, animationEasing, xValue) {

        return defaultFrom + (defaultTo - defaultFrom)
                * easingValueForProgress.getValue(animationEasing, xValue)
    }
}
```

Add this to your main.cpp:

```
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "easingvalueforprogress.h"
```

```
    EasingValueForProgress easingValueForProgress;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(
                "easingValueForProgress", &easingValueForProgress);
```

Now you can use it like this (instead of `NumberAnimation` object):

```
XValueAnimator {
    target: object_you_want_to_affect     // for example id of the object
    targetProperty: "property_to_affect"  // for example "x"
    from: 100
    to: 500
    easing: Easing.OutQuad                // omit to use Easing.Linear
    xValue: myXValue                      // your property holding values from 0 to 1
}
```

---

[Here](https://github.com/fhazubski/QtQuick-XValueAnimation) I provided working example project. Feel free to download and test it.

Comment: Thank you Filip, I am marking your answer as accepted. However, as time passed, I had more time to think about it all, and I believe I will not be taking the QML route. But if I will take it, I will use your answer. Thanks again!